# Teamcity nuget feed http authentication

Tags: vpn, authentication, teamcity

Nuget feed by team city  is working perfectly but there is a strange problem.

Local IP (http://192.168.xx.xx:9999/feed/../):
Listing through browser works
Accessing packages  through Visual studio 11 nuget works

VPN IP (http://55.xx.xx.xx:9999/feed/../):
Listing packages through browser works
Accessing packages  through Visual studio 11 nuget PROBLEM

GUEST Account:
Everything works fine, both on VPN and local IP (so its purely an authentication problem)

The problem is, we can't get the user to authenticate. Using the same credentials, no matter what we try we get 401. The server VPN ip is whitelisted in internet explorer intranet settings. Any ideas? Basically HTTP authentication is failing for the VPN although it shouldn't, since the browser works fine!

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with TeamCity thinking the server is called X and doesn't recognise the alias Y.

In my case the DNS CName didn't work, but the correct name did